# How to highlight searched for words using a regular expression

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

Hi 
I am working on a groovy application that requires me to highlight(add spans) to the word that is searched for.For instance given the text below :

```
youtube

[href="youtube.com] i am here , in Youtube[/a]
```

I want to search for the word "youtube" and when it returned the above text should look like this :

```
[span]youtube[span]

[href="youtube.com] i am here , in [span]Youtube[/span]  [/a]
```

The youtube word that is contained in the href or in the iframe must be ignored.
At the moment I have the following code :

```
def m = test =~ /([^<]*)?(youtube)/
println m[0]

def highLightText  = { attrs, body ->
        def postBody = attrs.text
        def m = postBody =~ /(?i:${attrs.searchTerm})/
        def array = []

        m.each{
            array << it as String
        }
        array.unique()

        String result = postBody
        array.each{
            result = result.replaceAll("${it}", "<span class='highlight'>${it}</span>")

        }

        out << result
    }
```

And it returns :

```
[span]youtube[span]

[href="[span]youtube[span].com] i am here , in [span]Youtube[/span]  [/a]
```

Can anyone help me with a regular expression that can select only words that are not contained in links or other tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A maintainable solution is unlikely to be achievable using regular expressions - the problem is too complex.

Parse your HTML into a DOM and consider only text nodes as being suitable for potential highlighting. Text nodes will, by definition, be only those pieces of content that are rendered and will not be element names, attributes/attribute values and so on.

The complexity of your problem is then reduced down to: how to do I find and highlight a string within another string?